# Copy Multiple Charts from Excel to Word

Tags: excel, vba, ms-word

I wanted to copy a Multiple charts from Excel and paste as link to word. So someone update data of chart and i can fetch the value directly in Word.

Word file have existing charts. I wanted to delete that chart and replace the same chart link from Excel

Their is a chance that particular chart location in word file can be go up or down as per data.

I have tried fallowing codes. But i dont know how can i incorporate the logic of particular location.

So request your kind suggestions.

You can refer this file

Excel with Chart: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1cg1BbMMbhwVEMMNJIODCNL9Zo0M7IKAu/edit?usp=sharing&ouid=112284850895007842303&rtpof=true&sd=true

Word File : https://docs.google.com/document/d/1i_sy3D-tCZIumQi0fhmPQbNKjKKfUcVu/edit?usp=sharing&ouid=112284850895007842303&rtpof=true&sd=true

**Following code i tried**

```
Workbooks.Open("D:\Charts.xlsx", UpdateLinks:=False).Activate

Sheets("Graph").Select

Dim WrdApp  As Word.Application
Dim WrdDoc As Word.document
Dim WrdRng As Word.Range
Dim WrdShp As Word.InlineShape

Dim chrobj As ChartObject
Dim Wrksht As Worksheet

Set WrdApp = New Word.Application
WrdApp.Visible = True
WrdApp.Activate

Set WrdDoc = WrdApp.documents.Open("D:\DASHBOARD.docx")

Workbooks("Charts.xlsx").Worksheets("Graph").Activate


For Each chrobj In ActiveSheet.ChartObjects

chrobj.Chart.ChartArea.Copy

Set WrdRng = WrdDoc.Goto(What:=wdGoToPage, Which:=wdGoToAbsolute, Count:=2)

With WrdApp.Selection
     .PasteSpecial link:=True, DataType:=wdpasteOLEObject
End With

Application.CutCopyMode = False


Next chrobj
```

Fallowing the place where i need a logic to select particular graph and replace

```
  Set WrdRng = WrdDoc.Goto(What:=wdGoToPage, Which:=wdGoToAbsolute, Count:=2)
    
    With WrdApp.Selection
         .PasteSpecial link:=True, DataType:=wdpasteOLEObject
    End With
```

Thank you in Advance

Comment: Do the existing charts in Word have names? Use that to find them.

Comment: @SolarMike Charts does not have name in words..Can you suggest me how can i do the naming of charts in word?